# Error in opening mongodb and cannot remove lock file

Tags: python, mongodb, database

When I run mongo in my terminal I get the following error :

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11
connecting to: test
2017-07-08T23:23:02.105+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2017-07-08T23:23:02.106+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6
```

As suggested in various answers, I tried this :

```
 $ sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock': No such file or directory
```

How should I resolve the error?

Comment: Have you tried another port? e.g. you can run `mongo localhost:12345`

Comment: Did you try the answer where you actually verified you actually installed the **"server"** and not just the client? Or the one where you even attempt to see if a **"server"** is running or pointing to the log where the **"server"** startup is failing? Because all I see here is attempting to connect with the **"client"** and nothing about the **"server"** which you are being told in the error message "does not exist".